# Finding rank of matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$A$ is a $3\times 4$ real matrix and $Ax=B$ is an inconsistent system of equations. What is the highest possible rank of $A$?

Since it is a $3\times 4$ matrix the rank possible is $3$. But since it is a inconsistent system we have no solution. Rank of matrix a is $2$ and augmented matrix is $3$. So highest rank possible for a  is $2$. Is it correct?

Comment: See [Rouché–Capelli theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%E2%80%93Capelli_theorem).

Comment: Okay I saw the theorem . And according to this link http://www.mathwords.com/i/inconsistent_system_of_equations.htm it says no solution for inconsistent system . @lhf

Answer (score 0):

The rank of a matrix is the dimension of the image of the associated linear map (multiplication by that matrix). You are given that $B\in\Bbb R^3$ is *outside* that image for $A$ (this is what inconsistency means), so indeed the image must have dimension strictly smaller than$~2$. It is easy to fond an example of an image of dimension$~2$ and a vector not in that image, so rank$~2$ is indeed possible. Your reasoning is basically correct, but you don't really need any theorem to arrive at the conclusion, just the notion of dimension and common sense.